"UV pixel mapping" a projection onto a planet
My problem is that i try to "UV map" an unwrapped jupiter onto points on a sphere and i did that but the texture doesnt rotate (just occasionaly flips 180, to be exact i see the poles of the planet) with the sphere, And i know i have a wierd system but i like the look and vibe of this. My code is janky and some parts are obsolete but for now i dont need to change that
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MakeSemiSphere : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numPoints = 100; // Number of points to generate
    public int RedPointPrc = 10;
    public float radius = 1.0f; // Radius of the sphere
    public float angle1;
    public float angle2;
    public float angle3;

    public Texture2D PlanetTexture;
    public RawImage image;

    private Texture2D OutputTexture;

    private void MakeTextureBlack()
    {
        OutputTexture = new Texture2D(100, 100);
        OutputTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                OutputTexture.SetPixel(i, j, Color.black);
            }
        }
        OutputTexture.Apply();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            MakeTextureBlack();

            for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
            {
                Vector3 v = GeneratePointOnSphere(i, numPoints, radius);
                Vector3 rotatedV = RotatePoint(v, angle1, angle2, angle3);

                // Scale and center the point on the 2D plane
                Vector2 FlatPoint = new Vector2(rotatedV.x, rotatedV.y);

                // Calculate spherical coordinates
                float theta = Mathf.Atan2(rotatedV.y, rotatedV.x);
                if (theta < 0)
                    theta += 2 * Mathf.PI;
                float phi = Mathf.Acos(rotatedV.z / radius);

                // Normalize Theta and phi to [0, 1] range
                float u = theta / (2 * Mathf.PI);
                float vNorm = phi / Mathf.PI;

                // Map to texture coordinates
                int x = Mathf.RoundToInt(u * (PlanetTexture.width - 1));
                int y = Mathf.RoundToInt((1 - vNorm) * (PlanetTexture.height - 1));

                // Clamp coordinates
                x = Mathf.Clamp(x, 0, PlanetTexture.width - 1);
                y = Mathf.Clamp(y, 0, PlanetTexture.height - 1);

                // Sample pixel color from PlanetTexture
                Color pixelColor = PlanetTexture.GetPixel(x, y);

                // Determine color intensity based on distance from center
                float colorIntensity = GetHowFarFromCenter(FlatPoint);

                // Blend colors based on RedPointPrc threshold
                if (i < numPoints * RedPointPrc / 100)
                {
                    // Red point
                    OutputTexture.SetPixel(Mathf.RoundToInt(FlatPoint.x + 50), Mathf.RoundToInt(FlatPoint.y + 50), Color.red * colorIntensity);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Sampled texture color
                    OutputTexture.SetPixel(Mathf.RoundToInt(FlatPoint.x + 50), Mathf.RoundToInt(FlatPoint.y + 50), pixelColor);
                }
            }

            // Apply changes to OutputTexture and update RawImage
            OutputTexture.Apply();
            image.texture = OutputTexture;

       
            angle1++;
            angle2 += 3;
            angle3 += 2;
        }
    }

    Vector3 RotatePoint(Vector3 point, float angleX, float angleY, float angleZ)
    {
        // Convert angles to radians
        float angleXRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * angleX;
        float angleYRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * angleY;
        float angleZRad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * angleZ;

        // Rotate around X axis
        Vector3 rotated = new Vector3(
            point.x,
            point.y * Mathf.Cos(angleXRad) - point.z * Mathf.Sin(angleXRad),
            point.y * Mathf.Sin(angleXRad) + point.z * Mathf.Cos(angleXRad)
        );

        // Rotate around Y axis
        rotated = new Vector3(
            rotated.x * Mathf.Cos(angleYRad) + rotated.z * Mathf.Sin(angleYRad),
            rotated.y,
            -rotated.x * Mathf.Sin(angleYRad) + rotated.z * Mathf.Cos(angleYRad)
        );

        // Rotate around Z axis
        rotated = new Vector3(
            rotated.x * Mathf.Cos(angleZRad) - rotated.y * Mathf.Sin(angleZRad),
            rotated.x * Mathf.Sin(angleZRad) + rotated.y * Mathf.Cos(angleZRad),
            rotated.z
        );

        return rotated;
    }

    float GetHowFarFromCenter(Vector2 vector)
    {
        Vector2 HowFar = new Vector2(50 - vector.x, 50 - vector.y);
        HowFar /= 50;
        return HowFar.magnitude;
    }

    Vector3 GeneratePointOnSphere(int index, int totalPoints, float radius)
    {
        // Golden ratio
        float phi = (1 + Mathf.Sqrt(5)) / 2;

        // Calculate spherical coordinates
        float theta = 2 * Mathf.PI * index / phi;
        float z = 1 - (2 * index + 1) / (float)totalPoints;
        float radiusXY = Mathf.Sqrt(1 - z * z);

        float x = radiusXY * Mathf.Cos(theta);
        float y = radiusXY * Mathf.Sin(theta);

        // Convert to Cartesian coordinates
        return new Vector3(x, y, z) * radius;
    }
}

I tried most of the things that would come to mind but im 100% sure that i just mist one line or didnt change a variable but im going blind from looking at the code
what i tried:
changing the rotation matrix,
making sure i writen the phi and theta projections right
changing the sample method

Would it not be way easier just to rotate the entire sphere instead? When dealing with 3D graphics you usually want to express transforms as matrices, and let the graphics engine do the transformations on the GPU.

i mean yea but my "game" kinda needs it this way or something similar

In that case you might want to explain why, and what your actual goal is. If you want a rotating texture you could rotate the geometry, the UV coordinates, or the actual texture. But I have a really difficult time understanding what your example code is supposed to do.
